# Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module Magento 2.3

Tags: javascript, magento, requirejs, magento2

i have problem with client Magento 2.3 shop. In console i see js error "Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(d){return c(d,a,b),d.mobile}".
I've read few topics about problem and it looks like calling not "defined" function/module.

Here is code what causes problem on every **frontend** page:

```
<script>
require.config({
    map: {
        '*': {
            wysiwygAdapter: 'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/tinymce4Adapter'
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Code is loaded from:

```
/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml
```

Here is what i've tried:

```
define('config', function () {
        require.config({
            map: {
                '*': {
                    wysiwygAdapter: '<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->getWysiwygAdapterPath(); ?>'
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

When i've used define error disappeared but i'm not sure about that solution. I had second magento 2.3 clean install there was the same magento file but not loaded one every page so on client shop script must be added from some module/loader. Is it correct way to solve this problem?

Many thanks for help. Have a nice evening!

Comment: Ever found solution to this problem? Unfortunately, I am facing same issue...